# i want to display a counter on the screen using innerHTML but it isnt working in a loop even when i use a sleep function?

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

actually i want a timer so that can countdown from my desired range to 0 .but using innerHTML just displays the 0:00 immediately without showing changes.i used sleep fuction so now the screen just stays the same and then displays zero and not like a countdown what to do?help!!!

```
function sleep(t){
   let timeenter code hereStart=new Date().getTime();
     while(true)
      {
       let elapsedTime=new Date().getTime()-timeStart;
       if(elapsedTime>t){
       break;
      }
    }
}

function startLoop(){

  let v1=document.getElementById("minutes-input").value;
  let v2=document.getElementById("seconds-input").value;
  let x1=document.getElementById("minutes");
  let x2=document.getElementById("seconds");

for(var i=0;i<v1;i++)
{
  x1.innerHTML=i;
  console.log(i);
  for (var j =1; j<=59; j++) {
     sleep(1000);
    x2.innerHTML=j;
    console.log(j);
  }
}
```

Comment: Use `setTimeout()` don't block the whole page with a `while()`.

Comment: There is no sleep in JavaScript, it just locks up the browser. You need to use setTimeout or setInterval.

Answer (score 1):

See if this helps. I know that CSS should be in an external file, but hey....
So, here it is...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<input type="text" id="minutes-input" value="1">
<input type="text" id="seconds-input" value="10">
<div style="border: 2px solid black; width: 100px; height: 15px;" id="minutes"></div>
<div style="border: 2px solid black; width: 100px; height: 15px;" id="seconds"></div>
<button type="button" onclick="setInterval(updateTime, 1000);">Start counting</button>

<script>
let v1=document.getElementById("minutes-input").value;
let v2=document.getElementById("seconds-input").value;
let x1=document.getElementById("minutes");
let x2=document.getElementById("seconds");

x1.innerHTML = v1;   // starting time in minutes
x2.innerHTML = v2;   // starting time in seconds

function updateTime() {
    x1.innerHTML = v1;
    if(v2 > 0) {
        x2.innerHTML = --v2;
        if(v1 === 0 && v2 === 0) {
          return;                    // stop counting
        }
        if(v2 === 0) {
            v2 = 60
            v1--;
        }
    }  
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If I need to explain something, just ask...